# Ruby - How to find out all dependencies of a given Gem in a .rb file?

Tags: ruby

How can I find out all dependencies of a given Gem in a .rb file
without having to rely on system() or similar external calls?

Consider this project:

https://rubygems.org/gems/diamond_shell

It has about 20 - 25 dependencies.

I need to traverse all dependencies, on all the linked
dependencies too, and populate an array with all of them.

Edit: Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Within *backtick* you can do `gem dependency <gem_name> -l`

Comment: Indeed but that requires me to call an external program. I would like to do this from within a .rb file, in pure ruby.

Comment: Inside the .rb file use Kernel#` method to execute the command.. and collect the output. It is very easy.

Comment: RubyGems are now standard, and how do you get that without calling tool that handle this? You should check RubyGems code and find out how to do this. Also why the hell you need that in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can yank the code out of `lib/rubygems/commands/dependency_command.rb`. Here's a simple method I made.

```
require 'rubygems/commands/dependency_command'

def get_dependencies name, local = true
  cmd = Gem::Commands::DependencyCommand.new

  dependency = cmd.gem_dependency name, nil, nil

  specs =
  if local
    dependency.matching_specs.uniq.sort
  else
    cmd.fetch_remote_specs(dependency).uniq.sort
  end

  dependencies = []
  specs.each do |spec|
    dependencies.concat spec.dependencies.sort_by { |dep| dep.name }.map { |dep| [dep.name, dep.requirement] }
  end
  dependencies
end

puts get_dependencies('diamond_shell', false)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be using Bundler for ruby gem management (http://bundler.io), the `bundle install` run generates a Gemfile.lock manifest file with all project gems and their dependencies. An example is below:

```
sunspot (2.0.0)
  pr_geohash (~> 1.0)
  rsolr (~> 1.0.7)
sunspot_rails (2.0.0)
  nokogiri
  sunspot (= 2.0.0)
teaspoon (0.7.8)
  phantomjs (>= 1.8.1.1)
  railties (>= 3.2.5, < 5)
```

This file can be easily parsed to get your dependency tree.

Comment: Thanks, this is quite good but requires bundler I believe. I think the answer by Max is better because I can avoid a bundler dependency, your answer of course also works so +1 too. Thanks.